# How to select in the minimum date for each id in SQL (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I select a minimum (exam) date for each group (Class ID) in SQL? The values are not necessarily distinct.

| ID | Date | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-02 | English |
| 1 | 2021-09-22 | English |
| 1 | 2021-04-07 | English |
| 1 | 2021-08-16 | English |
| 2 | 2020-10-02 | German |
| 2 | 2021-09-17 | German |
| 2 | 2021-06-13 | German |
| 2 | 2021-02-11 | German |
| 2 | 2021-02-19 | German |

I am looking for something like this:

| ID | Date | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-07 | English |
| 2 | 2020-10-02 | German |

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `GROUP BY` statement:

```
  SELECT id, min(date), subject
    FROM tab
GROUP BY id, subject;
```

In case the value of `subject` may be different within one `id` and you still only want one entry per `id`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS rn
   FROM tab
)
SELECT id, date, subject
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0e7de71e6110a89a441ea85e98efd14).